# How to implement builder inside my already defined class

Tags: java

I am trying to convert my class to support builder in order to prettify my code, this is the code I am using and I try to define my method called `addSMTPIntegration` to use builder.

this is my class:

```
public class IntegrationsPage extends SettingsTab {

    private static final By newIntegrationBth = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_add_new_button");
    private IntegrationsTable integrationsTable;
    private SmtpIntegrationForm smtpIntegrationForm;
    private ConfirmPopup confirmPopup;

    public IntegrationsPage(DriverWrapper driver){
        super(driver, "integrations",newIntegrationBth);
        integrationsTable = new IntegrationsTable(driver);
        smtpIntegrationForm = new SmtpIntegrationForm(driver);
        confirmPopup = new ConfirmPopup(driver);
    }

    public void addSMTPIntegration(String name, String server, String port, String fromAddress, boolean mode, String userName, String password){
        clickNewIntegrationButton();
        smtpIntegrationForm.chooseIntegration(IntegrationType.SMTP);
        smtpIntegrationForm.setIntegrationName(name);
        smtpIntegrationForm.setIntegrationServer(server);
        smtpIntegrationForm.setIntegrationPort(port);
        smtpIntegrationForm.setIntegrationFromAddress(fromAddress);
        smtpIntegrationForm.setIntegrationAuth(mode);
        smtpIntegrationForm.setIntegrationUserName(userName);
        smtpIntegrationForm.setIntegrationPassword(password);
        smtpIntegrationForm.clickSaveButton();
        LOG.i("SMTP configuration passed successfully");
    }

    private void clickNewIntegrationButton(){
        clickButton(newIntegrationBth);
    }

    public IntegrationsRow waitIntegrationRowTable(String configurationName) {
        return integrationsTable.waitRowDisplay(configurationName);
    }

    public boolean deleteIntegration(String integrationName) {
        integrationsTable.findRow(integrationName).clickRow();
        integrationsTable.delete(integrationName);
        confirmPopup.clickYes();
        return integrationsTable.findRow(integrationName) == null;
    }
}
```

I am trying to define my `addSMTPIntegration` method to support builder in a manner that I would be able to build it in the following way:

`smtpIntegrationForm.chooseIntegration(IntegrationType.SMTP).setIntegrationName(name).setIntegrationServer(server)`.... etc

This is my smtpIntegrationForm class:

```
public class SmtpIntegrationForm extends IntegrationCommonSection {


    private static final By integrationServerBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_server_name_txt");
    private static final By integrationPortBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_port_txt");
    private static final By integrationFromAddressBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_from_address_txt");

    SmtpIntegrationForm(DriverWrapper driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    void setIntegrationServer(String server){
        setText(integrationServerBy, server);
    }

    void setIntegrationPort(String port){
        setText(integrationPortBy, port);
    }

    void setIntegrationFromAddress(String address){
        setText(integrationFromAddressBy, address);
    }

    void chooseIntegration(IntegrationType integrationType){
        clickButton(By.cssSelector("li[class~='qa_" + integrationType.value + "']"));
    }
```

and this is IntegrationCommonSection class:

```
class IntegrationCommonSection extends PageElement {
    private static final By integrationNameBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_name_txt");
    private static final By integrationAuthBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_auth_bth");
    private static final By integrationUserNameBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_username_txt");
    private static final By integrationPasswordBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_password_txt");
    private static final By integrationSaveBthBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_save_bth");
    private static final By integrationTestBthBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_test_bth");

    IntegrationCommonSection(DriverWrapper driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    void setIntegrationName(String name){
        clearAndSetCharacters(integrationNameBy, name);
    }

    void setIntegrationAuth(boolean mode){ //true - with auth, false - no auth
        if(!isCheckBoxEnabled(integrationAuthBy) && mode) {
            clickButton(integrationAuthBy);
        }
    }
    void setIntegrationUserName(String userName){
        setText(integrationUserNameBy, userName);
    }

    void setIntegrationPassword(String password){
        setText(integrationPasswordBy, password);
    }

    void clickSaveButton(){
        clickButton(integrationSaveBthBy);
    }

    void clickTestButton(){
        clickButton(integrationTestBthBy);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, could you add more detail on what precise problem you are hitting and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: EDITED my question please review at the bottom of the question , thanks @AdamBurke

Comment: the builder should return the instance of the class that is inside.

Comment: In the instances I've seen, the "builder" class is a separate (though possibly nested) class from the object being built. See the bottom of [Builder Pattern in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-pattern-in-java/) from GeeksForGeeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to modify the methods of `SmtpIntegrationForm` with the return of `this` object so that you can construct the statements in a builder pattern. There is nothing you can do in `addSMTPIntegration()` method to achieve this.

`chooseIntegration(), setIntegrationName(), setIntegrationServer(), etc.` methods inside `SmtpIntegrationForm` should have return type of `SmtpIntegrationForm` and the last statement in these methods should be `return this;` in order for you to achieve this.

Make the changes as:

```
public class SmtpIntegrationForm extends IntegrationCommonSection {


    private static final By integrationServerBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_server_name_txt");
    private static final By integrationPortBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_port_txt");
    private static final By integrationFromAddressBy = Locators.findBy("settings_page_integrations_page_integration_from_address_txt");

    SmtpIntegrationForm(DriverWrapper driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    SmtpIntegrationForm setIntegrationServer(String server){
        setText(integrationServerBy, server);
        return this;
    }

    SmtpIntegrationForm setIntegrationPort(String port){
        setText(integrationPortBy, port);
        return this;
    }

    SmtpIntegrationForm setIntegrationFromAddress(String address){
        setText(integrationFromAddressBy, address);
        return this;
    }

    SmtpIntegrationForm chooseIntegration(IntegrationType integrationType){
        clickButton(By.cssSelector("li[class~='qa_" + integrationType.value + "']"));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question and added more info to my question , thanks

Comment: @tupacshakur added changes to my answer based on your modification. This should work.

Answer (score 2):

just return "this" :

```
SmtpIntegrationForm setIntegrationServer(String server){
        setText(integrationServerBy, server);
        return this;
    }
```